# About Shot blast machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering

> In addition to the machine parts we manufacture in our foundry we also produce high quality steel abrasive including low carbon round corn, cut wire, steel grit amongst others. We will be happy to advise you of the best abrasive solution for your requirements.

Here what does "corn" imply? Is it powder?

Comment: @Fred, I think the first paragraph is actually a quote from somewhere, and the OP is asking what they mean by "corn". So I'm VTC as unclear.

Comment: @Fred I agree with Wasabi in that this question is likely seeking clarification about a site's particular services.  However, we don't have enough context to understand what's being asked.  So I agree with the closing as "unclear."

Comment: FWIW, that marketing copy appears to be from the multiran.ru site.  Here's a linked to the cached copy: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YXIskd1k4sMJ:https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe%3Fa%3D4%26MessNum%3D349593%26l1%3D1%26l2%3D2+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Is it the shake of the shot, maybe?